# How can I group H1 to H6 in CSS?

Tags: html, css

Can I apply a CSS style to all headers from H1 to H6?

Answer (score 17):

If you mean that you want a CSS selector that targets all header elements, then no. You have to specify each tag name.

Example:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { margin: 5px 0; font-weight: bold; }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  color: #F00;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you can do this with css. use the following:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 { color:red; /* and the rest of your styles */ }
```

see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp for a good tutorial

Answer (score 1):

Nesting is not here yet, but soon...

for now... Since beginning of this year 2021, all mayor browsers support :is().

```
aside :is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) {
     all: unset;
     margin-block: 3ex; 
     font-weight: bold;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In CSS

If you want to apply `aside` class to h1~h6, you need write as below:

```
aside h1, aside h2, aside h3, aside h4, aside h5, aside h6 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

There seems no way to extract the common `aside` class.

#### But in SCSS

You could extract above to

```
.aside {
    h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
       text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not seem to provide anything that other answers don't already state.

Answer (score -4):

It seems to not follow convention at least in firefox

```
aside h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

will only affect h2 that is child of aside

```
aside h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

seems to effect all headers whether or not a child of aside.

Either firefox has a bug or CSS is not very logical in its syntax.

Comment: That's not a bug. You would have to write `aside h1, aside h2, ...` to apply only to `h1` ... `h6` child elements of `aside`.